# java Kerberos - unix kinit works, java not - Additional pre-authentication required

Tags: java, kerberos, pre-authentication

I've got problem with connection using Kerberos authentication.
If I use linux kinit with my custom KRB5.conf (connecting to windows kerberos AD), everything works smoothly.

```
kinit -kVt <MYKEYTAB> <MY_PRINC> -v
keytab specified, forcing -k
Using default cache: /tmp/krb5cc_11574
Using principal: HTTP/<MY_PRINC>@MBID.CZ
Using keytab: <MYKEYTAB>
Authenticated to Kerberos v5
```

After that i can smoothly use curl to authenticate against web application that has registered my user name:

```
curl -kLv -i --negotiate -u: "https://someserver/someapi/someoperation"
```

And i get desired response.

BUT if i use java kinit tool from jdk (same problem occurs in code) it says that i have problem

```
kinit -J-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -J-D"java.security.krb5.conf=<KRB5_CONF_LOCATION>" -t <MYKEYTAB> <MY_PRINC>
```

The problem is:

```
>>>KRBError:
     sTime is Thu Feb 27 07:14:38 CET 2020 1582784078000
     suSec is 280585
     error code is 25
     error Message is Additional pre-authentication required
     sname is krbtgt/<DOMAIN>@<DOMAIN>
     eData provided.
     msgType is 30
>>>Pre-Authentication Data:
         PA-DATA type = 19
         PA-ETYPE-INFO2 etype = 18, salt = SALT_FROM_PRINC, s2kparams = null
```

which leads to 401 unauthorized when i try to authenticate against server "https://someserver/someapi/someoperation"

Both kinits use exactly same keytab, principal and krb5.config file, only unix works.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please post the solution here if you have found one